# Passing data to controller and changing the view

Tags: view, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I have the following scenario:

I have a table with a list of book. Now, when I click on the selected rows, I want to send the book titles to the rental controller so that the controller can then call the appropriate view pass the book titles.

Here's the code for the table view:

```
  <button id="checkoutButton">Checkout</button>


<table id="books" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Book</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Registration Number</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Number In Stock</th>
                <th>Number Available</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@section Scripts{ 

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var titles = [];

        var table = $("#books").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/books",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "title"
                },
                {
                    data: "categoryId"
                },
                {
                    data: "registrationNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "volume"
                },
                {
                    data: "numberInStock"
                },
                {
                    data: "numberAvailable"
                },
                {
                    data: "author"
                }
            ]
        });
   $('#checkoutButton').click(function () {

            var obj = table.rows('.selected').data();

            if (obj.length == 0)
                console.log("No row selected");
            else {

                    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows('.selected').data().length; i++) {
                        console.log(table.rows('.selected').data()[i].title);
                        titles.push(table.rows('.selected').data()[i].title);
                }    

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Rental/print",
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        method: "POST",

                        data: JSON.stringify({ titles })
                    })

            }

        });
```

And here's the controller:

```
 public ActionResult print(Object [] titles)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(titles[i]);
            }


            return View("New"); 

        }
```

I haven't passed the title to the view yet because the view is not rendering at all. I have verified that the controller does get the data but it does not navigate to the "New.html". Although, if I manually navigate to this page, it does render. So, I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I will very much appreciate if you can point me to the right direction.

**Note:** I have not included the js code which selects multiple rows because I wanted to keep the code simple. Let me know if I need to show that too.

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: I see that you are using AJAX so you won't be navigating to a new page, only returning the AJAX portion of the page.  And I don't see a success: in your AJAX to do anything with the results.     I would think that you would want simple links to navigate and not use AJAX here.

Comment: So how can I construct a link which sends data to the controller and navigates to that controller's specified view?

Comment: I recommend doing some of the free mvc online tutorials.  In the mean time take a look at this example.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/use-controllers-and-views-to-implement-a-listingdetails-ui